# How do you get "keys" to appear in your answer text?

Tags: support, design

See the accepted answer in this post: [How do you position your hand to use the command key? What finger do you use?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3374/how-do-you-position-your-hand-to-use-the-command-key-what-finger-do-you-use)

What's the markdown the person used to turn the CMD curly symbol in to a floating key like that? I see those used all over stackexchange sites but there's no mention of how to do that in [the markdown editing help page](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the `<kbd>` tag. Enclose any piece of text—e.g. the ⌘ symbol—between `<kbd>` and `</kbd>`, and you get it to look like a keyboard key: 
<kbd>⌘</kbd>

Here's the "official" Meta Stack Overflow question on this: 
[How can I format as keyboard keys?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/26207/56285)